# CakePHP 3 - Select rows of containing table by date (year)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I've a table like below and now I wan't to get the rows by year. But when I try this I will get the following error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Matches.date' in 'where clause'

**My "Matches" table**

```
id | goalsfor   | goalsagainst  | date
1  | 5          | 4             | 2017-07-05 15:57:36
2  | 9          | 5             | 2017-07-05 17:06:31
3  | 7          | 8             | 2015-07-05 15:57:36
4  | 0          | 2             | 2014-07-05 15:57:36
6  | 5          | 4             | 2014-07-05 15:57:36
7  | 7          | 9             | 2014-07-05 15:57:36
```

**My query:**

```
 $playedMatches = $this->Players
    ->find()
    ->contain([
       'MatchePlayers' => [
          'Matches'
       ]
    ]);

 $playedMatches->where(['YEAR(Matches.date) =' => "2017"]);
```

**My associations:**

```
class PlayersTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('players');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('MatchePlayers', [
            'className' => 'MatchPlayers',
            'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
            'propertyName' => 'matches',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
    }
}

class MatchPlayersTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('matches_players');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Players', [
            'className' => 'Players',
            'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
            'propertyName' => 'player'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('Matches', [
            'className' => 'Matches',
            'foreignKey' => 'match_id',
            'propertyName' => 'match'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your choose of name confusing: MatchPlayers, MatchePlayers...

anyway: cake does not perform a single query when you have a belongsToMany relationship (and a Player belongsToMany matches trough matches_players)

so you have to specify your conditons in the contain clause

```
$playedMatches = $this->Players
->find()
->contain([
    'MatchePlayers.Matches' => function ($q)
    {
        return $q->where(['YEAR(Matches.date) =' => "2017"])
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake in your query, your syntax for contain is wrong, Try this,

```
$playedMatches = $this->Players
->find()
->contain([
   'MatchePlayers.Matches'
]);
$playedMatches->where(['YEAR(MatchePlayers.Matches.date) =' => "2017"]);
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: It doesn't works in my case because I must have the Matches by the MatchePlayers. I've added the relations to my question.

Comment: same error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MatchePlayers.Matches.date' in 'where clause'

Comment: use pr($playedMatches);die; before your where query. Check the array is empty or not and let me know whether you are getting the 'Date' column in the array or not? @CodeWhisperer

Comment: I got: [sql] => SELECT Players.id AS `Players__id`, Players.name AS `Players__name` FROM players Players. But not the associations. Inside the "defaultypes" array the '[Matches.date] => timestamp' is present.